# Show that the sums $\sum_{r \neq s} \frac{1}{\lambda_r -\lambda_s} - \sum_{r \neq t} \frac{1}{\lambda_r -\lambda_t}$ cancel out.

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, proof-explanation

Suppose that $\lambda_r$ are distinct real numbers with $|\lambda_r - \lambda_s|\geq \delta$ if $r \neq s$. And let $z_r$ be any complex numbers. Then why does the sum
$$
\mathop{\sum \sum}_{s \neq t} \frac{\bar{z}_s z_t}{\lambda_s -\lambda_t} \left\{ \sum_{r \neq s} \frac{1}{\lambda_r -\lambda_s} - \sum_{r \neq t} \frac{1}{\lambda_r -\lambda_t} \right\}
$$
vanish?

This is from the book Analytic Number theory of Iwaniec and Kowalski. However I can't understand the explanation given in the book. So I'm asking if there is another way to see this or if you can explain with more details what the book is saying (Cant really get hold of it at all). **It seems that the last two sums should cancel each other out as seen below.**

Proof from the book (this is all the details):

Note now that the estimate (*) amounts to finding the norm of the matrix $(\mu_{r,s})$ with $\mu_{r,s}=(\lambda_r-\lambda_s)^{-1}$ and $\mu_{r,r}=0$, thus we may assume that the vector $(z_r)$ is extremal. Since the matrix is skew-hermitian, the extremal vector is an eigenvector, i.e.
$$
\sum_{r\neq s} \frac{z_r}{\lambda_r-\lambda_s}=\nu z_s
$$
for some purely imaginary $\nu \in \mathbb{C}$. This shows that the last two sums cancel out.

The star (*) is an inequality
$$
\sum_r \bigg| \sum_{s\neq r} \frac{\bar{z}_s}{\lambda_r-\lambda_s} \bigg|^2 \leq \frac{\pi^2}{\delta^2} \sum_r |z_r |^2.
$$

Comment: Maybe some sort of telescoping taking place

Comment: If the sum is over *all* combinations of $r, s, t$, both sums are clearly the same, expressed with different indices.

Comment: @vonbrand Well that's true of course..

Comment: @vonbrand Since the first summation condition says $s \neq t$ that can't happen.. So you cant see it like that..

Comment: @Kplusn, then both are missing the same terms...

Comment: @vonbrand It seems to work if I'm not mistaken (I might be since the signs change for some of the terms..). Why are they doing it in so complicated way in the book?

Comment: @vonbrand Actually that doesn't work either, why would they be missing the same terms? Doesnt the condition just mean if the first one has some term the other cant have that exact same term?